# Spark SQL Date cache exception

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I've opened spark-sql console and

create the table
create table test1(date1 date, value int) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' 
stored as textfile ;

load data in the table

```
load data local inpath 'test1.csv' into table test1;
```

with the information

```
2015-01-01,10
2015-01-01,15
2015-01-02,10
```

I can execute select year(date1),month(date1),day(date1) from test

but if I run cache table test1;

I get this exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 17, 10.0.200.6): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableAny cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableInt
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificMutableRow.getInt(SpecificMutableRow.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.IntColumnStats.gatherStats(ColumnStats.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:172)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in Spark Cache implementation for dates.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6967

Solved in git